# What is the difference between SessionService and Ember.Service in ember 1.13?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am new to ember and I am developing an app in ember 1.13 with a back end in Rails. I understand that the session and data store handling has changed from previous versions of ember quite a bit. I am using `ember-simple-auth` In particular, I am trying to recuperate data from an authenticated user and cannot get it. Documentation in the web uses both `SessionService` and `Ember.Service` but the difference is not clear to me. Can somebody help either with an explanation or with a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ember you can create `services` same way you can create `routes` and `controllers`, it is class/paradigm that you use to build your application. You can create your own service by subclassing `Ember.Service`, if you have logic that needs to be shared across the app then it is good candidate for being a `service`.
If you are using `ember-cli` you can generate service with `ember g service <service-name>`

And `SessionService` is service that manages session provided/created by `ember-simple-auth`.

[ember guide services](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/applications/services/)
[tutorial creating services](http://www.programwitherik.com/ember-services-tutorial/)

Comment: So, at the same level as `services` one can also create `sessions` (`app/sessions`). Are these sessions independent of the `SessionService`?  I imagine that is the case. And if so, can you use both in parallel?

Comment: i think if they match names one will overwrite other, but you can always create service with different name `x-session` for example, but since `ember-simple-auth` provides full session management there is no need creating another service I think

Comment: Indeed, with the same name, the session is overwritten. So where is the correct place to define  `currentUser` data (retrieved using authenticated details) and attach it to the `SessionService`? Is this a servicei `app/services`?

Comment: I think you need to override the session provided by `ember-simple-auth` have look at their docs they should have such use case covered in docs